# How to make custom widget to upload image

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm making widget that can upload image and make a preview of image in widgets panels, so i used JQuery to add URL from `<intput type="file">` to `<img src"#">`, but it's not passing URL  to img, as static Html everything worked, but when i tried to implement it to WordPress it didn't work. In console not showing any errors.

What can be the problem or maybe there is an easier way to make this?

**function.php**

```
public function form($instance) {

    $name_1 = $instance["name_1"];
    $name_2 = $instance["name_2"];
    $picture_1 = $instance["pic_1"];
    $picture_2 = $instance["pic_2"];

        ?>
        <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name("name_1"); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['name_1'] ); ?>"><br>
    <!--Upload Image-->
        <input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('pic_1'); ?>" type="file" value="<?php echo esc_attr($picture_1); ?>" id="imgInp"/>
        <img class="pic-preview" src="#" alt="Your image" style="width:120px;height:120px;background:#eee;display:block;" />



        <script>
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(document).ready(function() {
            function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $j('.pic-preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
            }

            $j("#imgInp").change(function(){
                readURL(this);
            });
    });

</script>

    <?php

}//form


    public function widget($args, $instance ) {
        <div class="profile-pics">
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class='mfc-link'>
                    <img src='<?php echo esc_url( $instance['pic_1'] ) ?>'>
                </div>
                 <p><?php echo $instance["name_1"]; ?></p>
             </div>

        </div>
  <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put a console.log in your change event does it run?

Comment: no nothing output to console

Comment: try using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/): `$j(document).on('change', '#imgInp', function() {...`

Comment: awesome it worked! Do you know how can i pass the url to php variable so it can be displayed after i save it.

Comment: You could save it as custom meta option then pull it through where you need it. You will need to use AJAX if you want to send JS variable to PHP.